# sliding menu + new page on top (phonegap onsenui)

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I'm trying to present a new page on top of sliding menu. I'm trying to do something like this :

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <ons-screen>
      <ons-sliding-menu 
       behind-page="{{main.menuTpl}}" 
       above-page="{{main.homepageTpl}}">
     </ons-sliding-menu>
</ons-screen>
</div>
```

But when I do so the screen appears black and I can't push a new screen programatically by using scope.ons.presentpage ?? Any Idea how I can present a new navigator. What I'm trying to do essentially is checking if a user is new if so present him with a walkthrough which is a navigator with some pages and once he's done this navigator will be dismissed and the sliding menu + navigator will reappear. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
 scope.ons.presentpage()  // is wrong
```

Try

```
scope.ons.screen.presentPage()
```

Comment: the method ons.screen.presentPage doesn't seem to be available in the scope ? any reason why it's not available